# Jquery select on change

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, typeahead.js

I have a select box (Specie) and a typeAhead input field(Breed), Which i need to update on the change of selectbox, I have the following code.

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 profile-fields-margin-bottom">
    <select class="form-control select_field_style specie-breed" id="species" name="species" required>
        <option disabled selected>Select a Species</option>
        <option value="Dog">Dog</option>
        <option value="Cat">Cat</option>
        <option value="Horse">Horse</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 profile-fields-margin-bottom">
    <input id="breed" type="text" class="form-control charsonly" name="breed" placeholder="Breed">
</div>


$(document).on('change', '.specie-breed', function() {
    let specie = this.value;
    $('#breed').typeahead({
        source:  function (query, process) {
            return $.get('/get/breeds/' + specie, { query: query }, function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                return process(data);

            });
        }
    });
});
```

Its working but for the first time, The second time change doesn't change the values of the typeahead,

What am i missing here ?

Comment: It sounds like you may need to use a delegated event handler. Is the `process()` function re-creating the `.specie-breed` element?

Comment: You're actually creating a new typeahead instance for every single `onchange` event fired. That's going to slow the browser down tremendously after awhile.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yeah `process()` function re-creating the .specie-breed element.

Comment: @Terry then whats the best approach >

Comment: Use a delegated event handler. See the duplicate I marked for more information.

Comment: @Terry it should be fine. The browser should garbage collect any data associated with removed elements. Unless the OP is doing this several hundred thousand times performance shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan , Same result with `$(document.body).on('change', '.specie-breed', function(e) {`.

Comment: Try just `$(document).on(...` also, check the console for errors

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan exact same thing with no console errors

Comment: If you can edit the question to show your updated code, I'll re-open it for you

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, Question updated.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Didn't got anything from the community.

Comment: Could you please add **HTML** content or add code snippet ?

Comment: @AlpeshJikadra Question updated.

Comment: Could you please add complete url instead of **/get/breeds/** ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Its working but for the first time, The second time change doesn't
>   change the values of the typeahead,

I think that's because the second, third, etc. time, the AJAX URL doesn't get changed anymore; and that's because the `specie` remains as the value it was initially assigned to.

I mean, let's say you selected `Cat` from the drop-down menu; so the first `change` event of that menu gets triggered, and `specie` is set to `Cat`. However, when later you selected `Horse` (or `Dog`), the `specie` *from within the closure for the `source` option* remains as `Cat`.

[This Pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xjWvaq) may help you understand it.

So a simple fix would be to reference that `specie` to `this` and not `this.value`.

```
$(document).on('change', '.specie-breed2', function() {
    let specie = this; // Reference the Element.
    $('#breed').typeahead({
        source:  function (query, process) {
            return $.get('/get/breeds/' + specie.value, { query: query }, function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                return process(data);

            });
        }
    });
});
```

Or you can do it like this:

```
$('#breed').typeahead({
    source:  function (query, process) {
        if ( ! $( '#species' ).val() ) {
          return;
        }

        return $.get('/get/breeds/' + $( '#species' ).val(), { query: query }, function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            return process(data);

        });
    }
});
```

**UPDATE**

The actual solution, or *what you're missing* in your code, (I think) is: **Destroy `typeahead` on the `#breed` field before re-initializing `typeahead` on that field**.

```
$(document).on('change', '.specie-breed', function() {
    let specie = this.value;

    // Destroy existing instance.
    $('#breed').typeahead( 'destroy' );

    // (Re-)Initialize `typeahead`.
    $('#breed').typeahead({
        source:  function (query, process) {
            return $.get('/get/breeds/' + specie, { query: query }, function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                return process(data);

            });
        }
    });
});
```

That way, `specie` can be assigned or referenced to the `this.value` (i.e. the currently selected "Species"), and you'd get the correct value (e.g. `Cat` or `Dog`).

See [jQuery#typeahead('destroy')](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md#jquerytypeaheaddestroy).

Comment: The problem that remains in your first code snippet is that every time the value changes in the drop down list, the typeahead plugin is called, as if trying to reinitialize it (which doesn't work).  You corrected this in your second snippet where you completely eliminated the unnecessary event handler.

Comment: @gilly3 Yes, I was actually aware of that. I myself would probably use the second snippet or that I would not re-initialize `typeahead` on the same `input`/field. But it might be necessary for the OP to do the re-initialization, hence (in the updated answer) I suggested to destroy the `typeahead` instance before re-initializing it on the `#breed` field.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the docs](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md#datasets) `typeahead`'s `source` function can either accept two or three parameters. If you only use two, the second one, called `process` in your code, must be called with the result synchronously. In your code however, that callback is only served after an async AJAX request.

You have a few options here:

a) Use a synchronous/blocking GET. This is good for testing, but shouldn't be considered a real solution.

b) Use the `source` function's third parameter.

Please try this:

```
$(document).on('change', '.specie-breed', function() {
    let specie = this.value;
    $('#breed').typeahead({
        source:  function (query, syncResults, asyncResults) {
            $.get('/get/breeds/' + specie, { query: query }, function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                asyncResults(data);
            });
        },
        async: true
    });
});
```

If that doesn't help, make sure your AJAX requests are successful. The default handler on `$.get` works only for `success` but not for errors. In particular that `query` containing object looks suspicious on a GET request. Please try this line out in the console while your page is open:

```
$.get('/get/breeds/' + specie, { query: query }, function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

If that doesn't print your data, then you need to fix this part first.

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: asyncResults is not a function`.
AJAX call is fine there.

Comment: But getting the above exception.

Comment: I've added an explicit `async` option. Does that help? According to the docs that option should be inferred from the `source` signature.

Comment: @Gammer any chance you could put together a runnable sample? With full URL to that API and all. It's hard to debug without trying out things.